# How to show searching data to Datagrid tools

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datagrid

I have created Searching form and I want my searching data will show in datagridview tools. I also created a coding for call it but I cannot create a coding how to show it in datagrid.
here my code.

```
 koneksi.Open()
    cmd.Connection = koneksi
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tMember WHERE idmember = '" & txtcari.Text & "'"
    baca = cmd.ExecuteReader
    baca.Read()
    If baca.HasRows = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Data ada")
        DA_dg.Fill(DS_dg, "tMember")
        koneksi.Close()

    End If
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NoAlias I don't created a new table just show searching data on datagridview

Comment: @NoAlias I renewed my coding and doesn't work yet

Comment: You have to databind your grid. Also, you need to research sql injection immediately if not sooner. The code you posted is a textbook example. Parameterize your queries!!!

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry Sir, I am newbie in VB development and I just try to finishing my collage task. Can you tell it in easy way to do?

Comment: Shame on your professor for allowing queries like this. So sad that professors can't teach things the right way. You can do a quick google search for parameterized queries and you will find thousands of examples.